# Method overloading in MVC vs Web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

We can  do method overloading in MVC by different [ActionName("register")] or ActionVerb like HttpGet and HttpPost

But in Web API method overloading is possible without the attributes. For example, the following will work in Web API but in MVC it will not work.

```
 public string Register()
 {
     return "Register";
 }

 public string Register(int id)
 {
     return "register with id";
 }
```

If they both use the same routing engine, why does it work in Web API and not MVC?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please try again.

Comment: we can directly call http://localhost:57292/api/user/ and http://localhost:57292/api/user/2 in webapi ,no need of changing or attaching any action verb on method

Comment: But in same MVC we can not directly call the method it will give the errorThe current request for action 'register' on controller type 'UserController' is ambiguous between the following action methods

Comment: Question is both mvc and webapi  are implementing same Routing mechanism  but mvc will give the ambiguity error .

Comment: You should show the relevant routes that you've configured.

Comment: @Developersfield this is a good question. I have edited your question so it is clearer what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

method overloading or usually called function overloading is not an mvc archetecture but an OOPS concecpt or proprty  and here C# is an OOP language so thats why c# follows oops concept and hence its not at all related to web api or mvc but to language ......and you should be happy for that it does

You are cofusing it with MVC arch MVC in simple form is nothing but arrangig your code in a systametic way (easy def) nothing more then that its just an OCD version of .net framework where you know where to put what

Comment: Yes i understand MVC is architecture ,but Question is both mvc and webapi are implementing same Routing mechanism but mvc will give the ambiguity error and web api doesnot why

Comment: @Developersfield  there is a difference ... in mvc you are calling ActionResult or JsonResult or whatever but not a function  that return a specific return type in web API here these are two functions which return string  and i beleive actionResult dosent support overloading (i am not sure though)

Comment: @RAHULSR this does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

no it is not necessary that we have to return type action result it can by string or int or data type as see the below MVC code

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    //
    // GET: /User/
    //[HttpGet]
    public string Register()
    {
        return "Register";
    }

   // [HttpPost]
    public string Register(int id)
    {
        return "register with id";
    }
```

}

MVC code will give ambiguity error and WEB api code run return successfully

Comment: This is not the answer to your question so you should not be posting it as an answer. SO does not work like a forum. If this is a comment, then you should post it to a comment.